# Anomaly detection with Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, anomaly-detection

I have to create this mechanism: I have a dataset containing the statistics of a Git repository (for example number of commits per day, number of lines of code edited per day, etc. Not more than 4 or 5 fields).  I have to use an Anomaly Detection algorithm that analyzes this dataset and that launches an alert when different values than normal are detected.

For example: I launch this algorithms every end of the day, if on this day there were many more commits than usual, must trigger an alert.

I have to realize this system with Python.

From what I've read on the internet, to make this system you need to use the unsupervised machine learning.
In the past few months I've been taking a machine learning course and I know how to use the Python library's Sklearn (a bit). But I'm not a real machine learning expert and I don't know what to do.
Unfortunately on the internet I only find very theoretical tutorials (written by data scientist) and I do not understand what I have to do in practice.

Could someone advise me what to do and what to use?

Is there a more or less simple solution to my problem?
Thanks.

Comment: I think you're overthinking this by a large degree. For 4 or 5 fields, just take a look at the distribution of the values over some period and set a threshold above a certain percentile value. If you want something dynamic, you can recompute the threshold on a regular basis. Unsupervised machine learning here would be like using a cannon to squash a mosquito.

Comment: In any case, [*Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fit a [Gaussian Mixture Model](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html) or [Isolation Forest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html#sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture) model on the data and select a threshold for what to consider an anomaly.

As with all such problem, there is a tradeoff between recall and precision. In order to evaluate your solution, you should identify some anomalies by inspection and mark them as such. These can then be part of your validation and testing set. The training set would not contain anomalies (or only a small amount of them).

Answer (score 1):

The simple way of detecting anomalies/ outliers is to use the measures of central tendency, provided the given modality is under the criteria of normal distribution.

```
import numpy as np

inputs = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
print('inputs = ', inputs)
print('---------------')

mean = np.mean(inputs)
std = np.std(inputs)
print('mean = {0} \nstd = {1}'.format(mean, std))
print('---------------')

thresh = float(input('Input threshold ? '))
print('---------------')

for i in range(len(inputs)):
    if inputs[i] > (mean + thresh*std) or inputs[i] < (mean - thresh*std):
        print('{0} is an outlier '.format(inputs[i]))
    else:
        print('{0} is not an outlier '.format(inputs[i]))
```

Output:

```
-998 1989 67624 -178187817 -9876 179827863
inputs =  [-998, 1989, 67624, -178187817, -9876, 179827863]
---------------
mean = 283130.8333333333 
std = 103350924.95590967
---------------
Input threshold ? 1.5
---------------
-998 is not an outlier 
1989 is not an outlier 
67624 is not an outlier 
-178187817 is an outlier 
-9876 is not an outlier 
179827863 is an outlier
```